# Thymeleaf Como identifico un checkbox en especifico?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, thymeleaf

necesito saber como poder identificar cada uno de los checkboxes que voy generando cuando creo el objeto.
Este es la parte del código html:

```html
<tr th:each="entity : ${entities}">
                        <td><input class="seleccionar" type="checkbox" th:value="*{entity.seleccionado}" th:onclick="'javascript:check('+ *{entity.id} +')'"/></td>
                        <td th:text="${entity.fechaPago}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${entity.tipocuota.descrip}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${entity.tipocuota.monto}"></td>
</tr>
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en js:

```js
function check(id) {
        var v1 = $(".seleccionar").is(":checked");
        if (v1 == true){
         //Hacer algo
    }
 }
```

El id por parametro lo tengo que pasar si o si para hacer los posts que necesito si da true o false.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr th:each="entity : ${entities}">
    <td> <input class="seleccionar CLASE_CHECKBOX_{entity.seleccionado}" type="checkbox" th:value="*{entity.seleccionado}" th:onclick="'javascript:check('+ *{entity.id} +')'"/> </td>
    <td th:text="${entity.fechaPago}"></td>
    <td th:text="${entity.tipocuota.descrip}"></td>
    <td th:text="${entity.tipocuota.monto}"></td>
```

Consideraría ponerle una clase para **poder identificar** cada checkbox.

En todo caso también es una opción recorrer los elementos html para poder obtener el elemento por medio del evento utilizado con addEventListener

```js
        const botones = document.getElementsByClassName('evento');
        for (const boton of botones) {
            boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
                console.log(this);
            })
        }
```

```html
    <button class="evento">Boton</button>
```